# SQL Database Design - Combinations of factors affecting a final value

Tags: postgresql, database-design

The price of a service may depend on various combinations of factors. Example Tables:

- ServiceType_Duration (combination of 2 factors)

  ```
  +-------------+----------+--------+
  | ServiceType | Duration | Amount |
  +-------------+----------+--------+
  | Massage     |       30 |     30 |
  | Massage     |       60 |     50 |
  | Reflexology |       30 |     50 |
  | Reflexology |       60 |     70 |
  +-------------+----------+--------+
  ```
- DiscountCode (1 factor)

  ```
  +--------------+--------+---------+
  | DiscountCode | Amount | Percent |
  +--------------+--------+---------+
  | D1           | -10    | NULL    |
  | D2           | NULL   | -10%    |
  +--------------+--------+---------+
  ```

In this very simple example, a 30 minute massage with discount code D1 would have total price 30 - 10 = 20.

However, there may be many more such tables of the general format:

- Factor1
- Factor2
- ...
- FactorN
- Amount (possibly)
- Percent (possibly)

I'm not sure about having lots of 'pricing tables' when the general format is always going to be the same.  It could mean having to add/remove the same column from lots of tables.

Are the tables above OK?  If not, what's the best practice for storing this sort of data?

Comment: "*Assume that the total price is just the sum of the 4 looked-up values*" - in that case I would create a `base_price` table that has one row for each type of service (="lookup value"). And a table `therapy_price` that contains multiple rows per therapy that reference the base_price. Calculating the total price of a therapy is then a matter of summing all rows in the `therapy_price` table for that specific therapy.

Comment: I've edited the question. Is that any clearer?

Comment: Post data sample and desired output